# Durundal Kendo Window

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, kendo-ui, durandal

I am using Kendo with Durundal and Kendo -knockout for binding with knockout

I want to user Kendo Window and want to load content from another view/ viewmodel .. how can I call this in content: "#contactus" to open in window

example : hash of contacus view need to show in window

```
  window.kendoWindow({
                        width: "615px",
                        title: "Rams's Ten Principles of Good Design",
                        content: "#contactus",

                    });
```

Comment: What is "#contactus"? What is the window supposed to show?

Comment: example : hash of contacus view need to show in window

Comment: I don't think this can be done. Anyway somebody else may know the answer.